# List creation confusion

Tags: scheme, racket

I am currently going though the book "Realm of Racket" in an effort to expand my programming studies into a Scheme based language and found an issue with creating lists.
The book explains that creating a list can be done so far with 3 different functions: list, cons and '(). The problem lies in that when I apply the creation of a list of structure with
the '() method I get an error and when I do so using list it does not happen, here is the code

```
#lang racket

;;sBasic structure program

;;create student struct
(struct student (name id# dormhall))

(define alexander (student "Alexander" 447 'Nopehall))
(define graham (student "Bellman" 2341 'Nopehallb))
(define campana (student "chompana" 1234 'Nadahalla))

(define in-class '(alexander graham campana))

(student-name (first in-class))
```

Now, the problem lies in the definition of the in-class list, if I change

```
(define in-class '(alexander graham campana))
```

to

```
(define in-class (list alexander graham campana))
```

and then call the first instance of in-class with

```
(student-name (first in-class)
```

I don't get an error, but if I live it at '() then I get one. Why is that? is there an explanation based on language syntax or is it a bug?

Comment: anyone care to explain why is the question getting downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single quote character in front of anything like `'x` is an abbreviation for that same being the argument of quote special form `(quote x)`. This is essential syntax that all [lisp](/questions/tagged/lisp) dialects needs to distinguish code from data and it has existed since the very first Lisp paper in 1958.

Given your defined global variable, eg. `alexander`. If you were to write `alexander` in the interactions window you get `#<student>` as output and you can access items in it with `(student-name alexander)`, but if you evaluate `'alexander` you get the symbol `alexander` and you'll get a weird error when trying `(student-name 'alexander)`

Quoting means the argument (what is quoted) is unchanged. You expect the structure quoted to become exactly what you see so if I do `'(list alexander graham campana)` it won't become `(#<procedure:list> #<student> #<student> #<student>)` but `(list alexander graham campana)`, which is a proper list with the symbols `list`, `alexander`, `graham`, and `campana`. None of those symbols have anything to do with variables since they are all about the symbol and the fact that you have defined variable with that exact name is just a coincidence.

When you use `(list alexander graham campana)` `list` becomes `#<procedure:list>` and since it's a procedure if evaluates `alexander`, `graham`, and `campana` as variables and becomes their student objects and the result is a list of those. Try it:

```
(list alexander graham campana) ; ==> (#<student> #<student> #<student>)
'(alexander graham campana)     ; ==> (alexander graham campana)
```

Comment: It does make sense that ' is quote and that (list) would be used to construct lists. Why would the book say that the two are the same method for creating lists? could they be wrong? they literally say that cons, list and '() are the exact same way in which one can create a list even though the result expression of '() and (list) don't evaluate to the same result (as demonstrated in yout example)

Comment: @Alex_adl04 On page 45 they have forgot to quote every animal when you show how you make a list with `cons`, but you see the `list` version does quote each animal. The animals here are symbols so when talking about literal data it's true, but it's not true if you want values behind variables like you tried. The most important thing about lists are to get really good how to make a list with `cons` since every recursive procedure you ever get to write usually make a list part by part and `cons` is the only one that makes a list part by part. The other two are just more convenient somtimes.

Answer (score 1):

```
(define in-class '(alexander graham campana))
```

creates a list of symbols, not of instances of *student*. It's equivalent to

```
(define in-class (list 'alexander 'graham 'campana))
```

Comment: How is the list empty? the instance of student alexander was created before and then the list in-class was defined with 3 instances each one of them completely defined.Not only that but the example works just fine during runtime while the list of in-class is created using (list)

Comment: @Alex_adl04 Please explain what you mean with "I don't get an error, but if I live it at '() then I get one." It's hard to figure out what your problem is without seeing *all* the code you're using.

Comment: What I meant is that your answer had absolutely nothing to do with my question. I am not asking how to check if a list is empty, the list is not empty. I am mentioning how the book says that we can create a list  in Racket Scheme using (list bla bla bla) or '(bla bla bla) but when I use the quote method I get an error on the code when calling (student-name (first in-class))